# Django loaddata returns a permission denied for relation

Tags: django, postgresql

I am trying to load some data from a json file generated from a dumpdata on a django project to a new one with a new database using loaddata. The connection to the db seems to work but almost right away I receive a permission denied for relation django_content_type. I don't get what permission we are talking about. the db is postgres on a separate server and I connect to it through a vagrant virtual machine on my laptop that has a virtual environment and the settings.py has the settings to connect to the db.
Here is the Traceback:

```
Problem installing fixture 'djgprd1_dumpdata.json': Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/vagrant/devenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/loaddata.py", line 196, in handle
    obj.save(using=using)
  File "/home/vagrant/devenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/serializers/base.py", line 165, in save
    models.Model.save_base(self.object, using=using, raw=True)
  File "/home/vagrant/devenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 524, in save_base
    manager.using(using).filter(pk=pk_val).exists())):
  File "/home/vagrant/devenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 565, in exists
    return self.query.has_results(using=self.db)
  File "/home/vagrant/devenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 441, in has_results
    return bool(compiler.execute_sql(SINGLE))
  File "/home/vagrant/devenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 818, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/vagrant/devenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/util.py", line 40, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/vagrant/devenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql_psycopg2/base.py", line 52, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(query, args)
DatabaseError: Could not load contenttypes.ContentType(pk=29): permission denied for relation django_content_type
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The postgres user for this db was created automatically and I did not check the permissions, they were missing for this db so a `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE x for user y;` resolved the permissions problem. My bad.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you're exporting `ContentType` objects (did you `dumpdata` with `--all`?), is this by design?

The docs mention that you might want to use the `--natural` flag, that fixes problems such as this, see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/#django-admin-option---natural

Also see this quote:

> If you’re serializing data (for example, when generating fixtures) from a model that implements generic relations, you should probably be using a natural key to uniquely identify related ContentType objects. See natural keys and dumpdata --natural for more information.

Source: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/contenttypes/

Comment: I did a dumpdata without flags, and it's not by design, I'm trying now with --natural

Comment: You can also use `--exclude` to explicitly exclude the contenttype objects from the dump.

Comment: after reading the doc I'm still not sure to understand, won't I miss the contenttype objects in the new db? Can I safely move it around without them?

Comment: I was receiving this error because the user did not have the permissions. My bad, it was created automatically and I assumed everything was correct. After checking I realized the permissions were not there.

Comment: Yes, without contenttype some stuff won't work (see the contenttype doc page). But again, `--natural` should solve the problem.