# GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE Blog&Cart for user postgres

Tags: postgresql

I have been running my site in development mode. And I have added a lot of data to the database. Now I want to run the site in production mode and need to transfer all the data from one database to another.

I tried this and ran into an error -

```
(ECOMME~1) C:\Users\HP\Django Projects\EcommerceProject>python manage.py dumpdata products --format json --indent 4 > products/fixtures
Access is denied.
```

[image]

On this StackOverflow post ([Django loaddata returns a permission denied for relation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19222373/django-loaddata-returns-a-permission-denied-for-relation)) Bastian wrote -

The postgres user for this db was created automatically and I did not check the permissions, they were missing for this db so a `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE x for user y`; resolved the permissions problem. My bad.

I went into pgAdmin and tried to implement Bastians advice but got this error -

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "&"
LINE 1: GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE Blog&Cart for user postgres
                                             ^
SQL state: 42601
Character: 38
```

Here are my database details (I have modified some of them for confidentiality purposes).

```
DATABASES = {
    
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.contrib.gis.db.backends.postgis',
        'NAME': 'Blog&Cart',
        'USER': 'postgres',
        'PASSWORD': 'C----------',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '5432'
    }


}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The ampersand, **`&`** is a reserved character.  You will need to escape it using double quotes:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE "Blog&Cart" for user postgres
```