# python manage.py dumpdata Access is denied

Tags: python, django

I got the error message -

```
(ECOMME~1) C:\Users\HP\Django Projects\EcommerceProject>python manage.py dumpdata products --format json --indent 4 > products/fixtures
Access is denied.
```

I assumed it was because I had changed my databases because the default databases are not sufficient if you want mapping functionality.

I read the post [Django loaddata returns a permission denied for relation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19222373/django-loaddata-returns-a-permission-denied-for-relation) and asked [GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE Blog&Cart for user postgres](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64637333/grant-all-privileges-on-database-blogcart-for-user-postgres/64637355#64637355).

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the answer was much simpler than first anticpated. I needed to write -

```
Python manage.py dumpdata products --format json --indent 4 > products/fixtures/products.json
```

I originally was not defining the filetype or filename for the file that would contain the data.

`products/fixtures/products.json` means make a file called products (with file extension json) and put it in the folder fixtures which can be found in the folder products. One of my apps is called products.